# Can't make div full width inside scrollable container

Tags: html, css

I'm building out a new website with Gatsby.js, but I've run into a little issue with some of the CSS for code blocks, and as CSS isn't really my forte I haven't been able to resolve it so far. Runnable snippet below:

```css
.prism-code {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: initial;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.token {
  display: inline-block;
}

p>code,
li>code {
  background: rgb(1, 22, 39);
  color: rgb(214, 222, 235);
  padding: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}

.gatsby-highlight {
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow: auto;
}

gatsby-highlight>code[class*="language-"],
.gatsby-highlight>pre[class*="language-"] {
  word-spacing: normal;
  word-break: normal;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  tab-size: 4;
  hyphens: none;
}

.line-number-style {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  width: 1.2em;
  user-select: none;
  opacity: 0.3;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.highlight-line {
  background-color: rgb(2, 55, 81);
  border-left: 4px solid rgb(2, 155, 206);
}

.highlight-line .line-number-style {
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: calc(1.2em - 4px);
  left: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gatsby-highlight" data-language="flow">
  <pre class="prism-code language-flow" style="background-color: rgb(40, 44, 52); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 20px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;"><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">1</span><span class="token comment" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">//@flow</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">2</span><span class="token plain"></span><span class="token keyword module" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">import</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token imports punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">{</span><span class="token imports"> useCallback</span><span class="token imports punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token imports"> useState</span><span class="token imports punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token imports"> useEffect </span><span class="token imports punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">}</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token keyword module" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">from</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token string" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">"react"</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">;</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">3</span><span class="token plain" style="display: inline-block;">
</span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">4</span><span class="token plain"></span><span class="token keyword" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">function</span><span class="token plain"> useFetch</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">&lt;</span><span class="token constant" style="color: rgb(90, 155, 207);">T</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">&gt;</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token plain">url</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">string</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> query</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">string</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">{</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">5</span><span class="token plain">  data</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">?</span><span class="token constant" style="color: rgb(90, 155, 207);">T</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">6</span><span class="token plain">  loading</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">7</span><span class="token plain">  error</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">8</span><span class="token plain"></span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">}</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">void</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">{</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">9</span><span class="token plain">  </span><span class="token keyword" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">const</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token plain">data</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> setData</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">?</span><span class="token constant" style="color: rgb(90, 155, 207);">T</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">?</span><span class="token constant" style="color: rgb(90, 155, 207);">T</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">?</span><span class="token constant" style="color: rgb(90, 155, 207);">T</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">|</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">?</span><span class="token constant" style="color: rgb(90, 155, 207);">T</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">void</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token function" style="color: rgb(121, 182, 242);">useState</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">null</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">;</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">10</span><span class="token plain">  </span><span class="token keyword" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">const</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token plain">loading</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> setLoading</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">|</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">void</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token function" style="color: rgb(121, 182, 242);">useState</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token boolean" style="color: rgb(255, 139, 80);">false</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">;</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">11</span><span class="token plain">  </span><span class="token keyword" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">const</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token plain">error</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> setError</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">|</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">void</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token function" style="color: rgb(121, 182, 242);">useState</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token boolean" style="color: rgb(255, 139, 80);">false</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">12</span><span class="token plain" style="display: inline-block;">
</span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">13</span><span class="token plain">  </span><span class="token keyword control-flow" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">return</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">{</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">14</span><span class="token plain">    data</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> data</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">15</span><span class="token plain">    loading</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> loading</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">16</span><span class="token plain">    error</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> error</span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">17</span><span class="token plain">  </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">}</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> fetchData</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">;</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">18</span><span class="token plain"></span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">}</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">;</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">19</span><span class="token plain" style="display: inline-block;">
</span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">20</span><span class="token plain"></span><span class="token keyword module" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">export</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token keyword module" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">default</span><span class="token plain"> useFetch</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">;</span><span class="token plain"></span></div></pre>
</div>
```

Basically, it's using MDX to support Markdown with code blocks, and I've implemented the functionality to highlight lines of code within the code block for emphasis. These lines are styled using the class `highlight-line`. Each line also has the `token-line` class.

What I'm struggling with is the size of the div with the `highlight-line` class. It's spanning the width of the parent div, but that is scrollable, so it's just highlighting the leftmost part to the same width as the scrollable. As a result, if you view it on mobile or in any other context where the content is wider than the scrollable, and scroll to the right, the content falls outside the highlighted block. The highlighted block should span the full width of the scrollable div.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this out

```
.gatsby-highlight {
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; /*this line can you make div full width inside scrollable container */
}
```

Comment: No, doesn't make any visible difference

Answer (score 0):

Just cracked this. Solution was to set the following CSS rules on the `<pre>` tag:

```
{
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: initial;
}
```

Since this is in React/Gatsby it made more sense to add these to the inline rules on the `<pre>` tag and this is shown in the revised snippet below:

```css
.prism-code {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: initial;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.token {
  display: inline-block;
}

p>code,
li>code {
  background: rgb(1, 22, 39);
  color: rgb(214, 222, 235);
  padding: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}

.gatsby-highlight {
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow: auto;
}

gatsby-highlight>code[class*="language-"],
.gatsby-highlight>pre[class*="language-"] {
  word-spacing: normal;
  word-break: normal;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  tab-size: 4;
  hyphens: none;
}

.line-number-style {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  width: 1.2em;
  user-select: none;
  opacity: 0.3;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.highlight-line {
  background-color: rgb(2, 55, 81);
  border-left: 4px solid rgb(2, 155, 206);
}

.highlight-line .line-number-style {
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: calc(1.2em - 4px);
  left: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gatsby-highlight" data-language="flow">
  <pre class="prism-code language-flow" style="background-color: rgb(40, 44, 52); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 20px; min-width: 100%; overflow: initial; float: left;"><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">1</span><span class="token comment" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">//@flow</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">2</span><span class="token plain"></span><span class="token keyword module" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">import</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token imports punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">{</span><span class="token imports"> useCallback</span><span class="token imports punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token imports"> useState</span><span class="token imports punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token imports"> useEffect </span><span class="token imports punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">}</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token keyword module" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">from</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token string" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">"react"</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">;</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">3</span><span class="token plain" style="display: inline-block;">
</span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">4</span><span class="token plain"></span><span class="token keyword" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">function</span><span class="token plain"> useFetch</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">&lt;</span><span class="token constant" style="color: rgb(90, 155, 207);">T</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">&gt;</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token plain">url</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">string</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> query</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">string</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">{</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">5</span><span class="token plain">  data</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">?</span><span class="token constant" style="color: rgb(90, 155, 207);">T</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">6</span><span class="token plain">  loading</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">7</span><span class="token plain">  error</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">8</span><span class="token plain"></span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">}</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">void</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">{</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">9</span><span class="token plain">  </span><span class="token keyword" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">const</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token plain">data</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> setData</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">?</span><span class="token constant" style="color: rgb(90, 155, 207);">T</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">?</span><span class="token constant" style="color: rgb(90, 155, 207);">T</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">?</span><span class="token constant" style="color: rgb(90, 155, 207);">T</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">|</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">?</span><span class="token constant" style="color: rgb(90, 155, 207);">T</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">void</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token function" style="color: rgb(121, 182, 242);">useState</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">null</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">;</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">10</span><span class="token plain">  </span><span class="token keyword" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">const</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token plain">loading</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> setLoading</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">|</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">void</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token function" style="color: rgb(121, 182, 242);">useState</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token boolean" style="color: rgb(255, 139, 80);">false</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">;</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line highlight-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">11</span><span class="token plain">  </span><span class="token keyword" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">const</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token plain">error</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> setError</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">|</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">boolean</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token arrow operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=&gt;</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token type tag" style="color: rgb(252, 146, 158);">void</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">=</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token function" style="color: rgb(121, 182, 242);">useState</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">(</span><span class="token boolean" style="color: rgb(255, 139, 80);">false</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">)</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">12</span><span class="token plain" style="display: inline-block;">
</span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">13</span><span class="token plain">  </span><span class="token keyword control-flow" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">return</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">[</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">{</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">14</span><span class="token plain">    data</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> data</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">15</span><span class="token plain">    loading</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> loading</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">16</span><span class="token plain">    error</span><span class="token operator" style="color: rgb(215, 222, 234);">:</span><span class="token plain"> error</span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">17</span><span class="token plain">  </span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">}</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">,</span><span class="token plain"> fetchData</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">]</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">;</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">18</span><span class="token plain"></span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">}</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">;</span><span class="token plain"></span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">19</span><span class="token plain" style="display: inline-block;">
</span></div><div class="token-line" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span class="line-number-style">20</span><span class="token plain"></span><span class="token keyword module" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">export</span><span class="token plain"> </span><span class="token keyword module" style="color: rgb(197, 165, 197);">default</span><span class="token plain"> useFetch</span><span class="token punctuation" style="color: rgb(141, 200, 145);">;</span><span class="token plain"></span></div></pre>
</div>
```